# angularjs undefined main module when minifying using typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, minify, angularjs-module

I am trying to minify and uglify my angularjs + typescript app using grunt-minified. Currently I am getting an error that my main module for the app is not available when I minify. I know why this is occuring due variable names no longer matching the names of the modules they reference. How would I set up annotation so angular is able to identify my main module after minification?

```
declare module BB {

}

    module BB.MyModule {

        // initialize the module
        export var module = angular
            // load the dependencies
            .module("MyModule", [
                // dependancies
            ]);

    }
```

This basic setup is working fine unminified, but MyModule is not defined when I minify it. How would I go about defining for safe minification?

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
declare module BB {

}
```

Probably `BB` has been minified to something else. That would make `module BB.MyModule` be different from `BB`.

Solution: Your code is *already* safe for minification *if* the point where you *bootstrap* angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap is minified through the same pipeline as `BB.module` is passed through.

Comment: So your saying to simply drop declare from module BB only and the problem will be resolved?

Comment: No. I am saying that your code is *already* safe for minification *if* the point where you *bootstrap* angular https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.bootstrap  is minified through the same pipeline as `BB.module` is passed through.

Comment: How would I go about determining that angular.bootstrap is being minified on the same pipeline as BB.module? I tried running bootstrap just after initialization of MyModule and loading of controllers, services, directives, etc. No effect though.

Comment: `but MyModule is not defined when I minify it` Run `angular.module('MyModule')` in the browser. Is it `undefined`?